# FusionCharts.register is not a function when bundling with WebPack

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack, fusioncharts

I'm developing an Angular 2 application and using webpack to bundle my application together. One of my components imports the fusioncharts library stored in /lib/fusioncharts directory in the root of my project.

Note: I dont have the fusioncharts module in node_modules.

I was able to configure my aliases, provide plugin correctly (the bundle increased in size, and I was able to verify, through the network tab that fusion charts existed):

import statement:

```
import FusionCharts from 'fusioncharts'
```

alias statement:

```
'fusioncharts' : '/lib/fusioncharts/fusioncharts.js'
```

provide plugin:

```
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
  $: 'jquery',
  jQuery: 'jquery',
  'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
  'window.PR': 'prettify',
  FusionCharts: 'fusioncharts',
  'fusionthemes':'fusionthemes'
})
```

This lead to my bundle increasing in size, and in the network tab, I was able to locate my fusioncharts code.

Webpack didnt throw any errors during the build, but when I launched my application, I received this in my browser console:

[image: FusionCharts Register is not a function]

Is there anything else that I'm missing?

[image]

Comment: Hey, FusionCharts has released 3.13 version where you can import the files in a modular way, for example, if you want to render column2d chart you can only include fusioncharts core files and column2d library files, also they have updated angular-fusioncharts plugin check their GitHub link  - https://github.com/fusioncharts/angular-fusioncharts